# Facebook webhook for page unable to create

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-webhooks

Created an app and for that trying to create webhook, but in the droplist the 'Page' object is not showing up, only 'User', 'Application', 'Permission', 'Native Components' and 'Certificate Transperancy'.

How can we create a webhook for the Page object?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 6):

There is a bug right now that does not let you subscribe to Pages: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/553848658320920

You should subscribe to the bug to get informed about updates.